# Confused about endpoint associated with delete and put

Tags: node.js, rest, http, express, mongoose

In my app i have stores and products, in my store side i have a reference to products, my daubt now is how i set the route to delete a product for a store

should i do something like this `router.delete('products/:id')` this deletes a product since the store has a reference i just need to delete the reference, but my store has a id actually my store is my user, so i want to be sure that there is a user to be able to delete something i was imaginating something like this:

`router.delete('stores/:id/products/:id')`, but that feels kinda strange, what you guys think about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your concern is that you have two parameters `id` in request string. Express supports specifying many parameters and you can name them whatever you like, they should be parsed and available to you as variables later (`req.params.productId`).

So you can do

```
router.delete('stores/:storeId/products/:productId')
```

Additional information you can find in [express routing documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).